# filter in a dataframe by values of another data frame in python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

i have two data frames:
**df1** :

```
     ID  COUNT
0   202485  6
1   215893  8
2   181840  8
3   168337  7
```

and another dataframe
**df2**:

```
ID
0   202485
1   215893
2   181840
```

i want to filter /left join the two dataframes:
desired result is

```
ID  COUNT
0   202485  6
1   215893  8
2   181840  8
```

i tried `df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='ID')` : error like ou are trying to merge on object and int64 columns

also used `isin`, but didn't work.

```py
list=df1['ID'].drop_duplicates().to_list()
df1[df1['ID'].isin(list)]
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[202485,215893,181840,168337],'COUNT':[6,8,8,7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[202485,215893,181840]})
out_df = pd.merge(df1,df2)
print(out_df)
```

This gives the desired result

```
      ID    COUNT
0   202485  6
1   215893  8
2   181840  8
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. i want to pass dynamically. Hence by list name , i need to pass. While doing so, i get this error:You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat. May be some issue with format/data type